# Bug when checking back/forward scrolling in UIPageViewCotroller

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to load appropriate images from an array into my `UIPageViewController`'s Views. 
I have 3 views which I cycle through in order to prevent crashes.

I keep track whether I am scrolling forward or backwards but sometimes when flipping forth and back really quick, I run into a bug that flips the direction and than I get the same view repeating for couple of scrolls.

Here is the function that updates the local variable index when scrolling completes

```
func pageViewController(pvc: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
     if completed {
                let thisPage = pvc.viewControllers!.last as! PageContentViewController
                let currentIndex = thisPage.pageIndex

                let lastIndex = lastPage.pageIndex
                  if(currentIndex > urlIndex){   
                    urlIndex += 1
                }else if(currentIndex < urlIndex) {
                    urlIndex -= 1
                }else{

                }
            }
        }
```

And here is the rest of my `UIPageViewController` code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dataSource = self
        delegate = self
}

   private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [PageContentViewController] = {
    return [self.newPageContentViewController(),
            self.newPageContentViewController(),
            self.newPageContentViewController()
    ]
}()

private func newPageContentViewController() -> PageContentViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageContentViewController") as! PageContentViewController
}

private func getNextViewController() -> PageContentViewController{

    let scrollView = orderedViewControllers.removeAtIndex(0)
    orderedViewControllers.append(scrollView)
    return scrollView
}

private func getPreviousViewController() -> PageContentViewController{

    let scrollView = orderedViewControllers.removeLast()
    orderedViewControllers.insert(scrollView, atIndex: 0)
    return scrollView
}

  func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
{
    guard urlIndex > 0 else {
        return nil
    }

    let previousUrlIndex = urlIndex - 1


    return getViewControllerAtIndex(previousUrlIndex, next: false)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
{

    let nextUrlIndex = urlIndex + 1
    guard arrayRouteName.count > nextUrlIndex else{
        return nil
    }


    return getViewControllerAtIndex(nextUrlIndex, next: true)
}

func getViewControllerAtIndex(index: NSInteger, next: Bool) -> PageContentViewController
{

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    var pageContentViewController:PageContentViewController
    if(next){
        pageContentViewController = getNextViewController()
    }else{
        pageContentViewController = getPreviousViewController()
    }
  pageContentViewController.localImage = arrayLocalImage[index]


    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index
    pageContentViewController.view.clipsToBounds = true
    return pageContentViewController
}
```

Comment: I think yo have made this more complicated than it needs to be. Just allocate a new view controller when required and let the old ones get released.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have tried that. Because I am using haneke swift to fetch and cache images it actually causes  crashes when i swipe too fast. This is the easiest way I could find to prevent such crashes.

Comment: The loading and fetching of images shouldn't be related to the management of view controllers. You should solve the crash

Comment: @Paulw11 I have tried to solve the crash but I think it happens because haneke tries to finish the fetches even though the view doesn't exist (or doesnt manage memory fast enough) And the crash happens even though my memory usage remains constant and low and it doesnt return any errors

Comment: You need to make sure that youmkeepmthe reference to your view controller and/or check nil. Using `weak self` in closures can be a cause of this

Comment: I know that I need to release the view controller but the crash was happening despite the fact that the controller was released properly. (if it wasnt than i would have a memory leak and my memory usage wouldnt remain constant which it did)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124085/discussion-between-paulw11-and-xitcod13).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix the problem. I have removed the `pageViewController`function from the `UIPageControllerDelegate` an simply chaged my `pageViewController` functions in my data source to get the index from viewController like so

```
 func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
{ 
let index = ((viewController as! UIPageContentViewController).pageIndex) - 1
guard index < 0 {
    return nil
}

return getViewControllerAtIndex(index, pageContentViewController: getPreviousViewController() ) 
}
```

and it behaves like it should.